# Is there anyway to change the layout of AD B2C update your password page when user login at the first time

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

When we create a new Azure AD account and force user change password at first time login, then when user login it will display the page to ask user to change password call "Update your password" page. We need to add more information about the password rule to original "Update your password" page of AAD.

My question is that can we do that?

I am very appreciated any help.
Thank you very much.

[This is "update your password" page when new user login at the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FudoP.png)

Comment: I guess the Screenshot which you shared is for the Azure AD Account but your question headline mentioned about B2C and there is basic change you can do in the page with the help of Company Branding feature like logo change, background change etc. not the entire page.

Comment: Thanks @RohitPrasad. I just think that we can change the layout of signin page then we can do for "update password" too, as it is in the flow of login. When the first time you login it will display the page to change default  password.